# PHP replacing entire string if it contains integer

Tags: php, string, replace

My script lists out files in the directory. I am able to use preg_match and regex to find files whose filenames contain integers.

However, this is what I am unable to do: I want an entire string to be omitted if it contains an integer.

Despite trying several methods, I am only able to replace the integer itself and not the entire line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post your code too.

Answer (score 6):

```
if (preg_match('/\d/', $string))
    $string = "";
```

This will turn a string into an empty one if it has any number in it.

Comment: He said "I want an entire string to be omitted if it contains ..." not "set to zero length".

Comment: @rub doesn't matter. If he's going to append the resulting string to a file/echo it, appending an empty string is the same as appending nothing.

Comment: Artefacto, from his description, it looks like he has already an array with filenames.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, this should be sth. like:

```
$files = array();

$dirname = 'C://Temp';
$dh = opendir($dirname) or die();

while( ($fn=readdir($dh)) !== false ) 
    if( !preg_match('/\d+|^\.\.?$/', $fn) )
       $files[] = $fn;

closedir($dh);

var_dump($files);
```

... which reads all file names and stores them (except these with numbers and ../.) in an array '$files', which itself gets displayed at the end of the snipped above. If that doesn't fit your requirement, you should give a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do

Regards

rbo